# suppress an entry from list of figures/tables in koma script

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, koma-script

While I don't regret switching a thesis to KOMA script, I do (sometimes) regret stopping using the `caption` package even though it works fine with `scrreprt`! I need a solution that won't require using the `caption` package. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading, figuresignature}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\NOcaption[1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\figureformat}{}
  \renewcommand*{\tableformat}{}
  \renewcommand*{\captionformat}{}
  \addtocounter{\@captype}{-1}
  \caption{#1}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\clearpage

\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\NOcaption{}
\begin{tabular}{c}
A table
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
A figure
\NOcaption{}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]


\end{document}
```

Using the above combination, the caption does not appear in the main text, however, there's an entry for the figure/table in the lists.

**Edit:**
The whole point of defining a new command `NOcaption` is to save my self from renewing `figureformat`, `tableformat` and `captionformat` at every table or figure. It was taken from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66099/suppressing-figure-numbers-in-koma-script-captions?rq=1) question. I can see why this is a bit confusing because the correct definition should be:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\NOcaption{% %NO arguments any more.
  \renewcommand*{\figureformat}{}
  \renewcommand*{\tableformat}{}
  \renewcommand*{\captionformat}{}
  \addtocounter{\@captype}{-1}
  \caption{}}
\makeatother
```

Then I would just use `\NOcaption` instead of `\NOcaption{}`

Putting things in terms of the caption package, I'm looking for an equivalent of `list=no` in KOMA scrpt, see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14124/subfig-koma-script-caption-how-to-suppress-some-list-of-figures-entries?rq=1) answer.

---

**Edit:** I should have put this in the MWE, I'm also using `hyperref` and `hypcap`. This is why I'm trying to put an 'empty' caption in the first place as `hypcap` gives an error if no caption was found.

```
Package hypcap Error: You have forgotten to use \caption.

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypercap}
```

Comment: You could simply not use `\caption` inside `\Nocaption` but put the text inside a `\parbox` or whatever.

Comment: I must be missing something, why not just not use `\caption` ?

Comment: I don't want the caption to appear in the main text nor an entry for the figure/label in the list of figures/tables.

Comment: Try `\newcommand\NOcaption{\begingroup\def\addtocontents##1##2{}\expandafter\endgroup\caption}` (not guaranteed).

Comment: @AbdulhaqElhouderi I don't understand your comment. Why simply not using \caption, as David and I suggested? Why not using `\parbox{\linewidth}{#1}` (or something else) instead of `\caption{#1}`?

Comment: I have edited the question, I hope it makes sense now

Comment: @tohecz it doesn't work, although the file compiles successfully. There is still an entry at the lof/lot.

Comment: @AbdulhaqElhouderi No It is still not clear why you have `\caption` in your figure if you do not want a caption?

Comment: You could just remove the \NoCaption lines from your document and get some output, please say in what way your desired output differs from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want captions just omit the `\caption` command there is no need to redefine all the caption internals For `hycap` you need to turn off its mechanisms as described in its manual:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading, figuresignature}
\usepackage{graphicx,hycap}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\clearpage

\lipsum[1]
\capstartfalse
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
A table
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\capstarttrue

\lipsum[2]
\capstartfalse
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
A figure
\end{figure}
\capstarttrue

\lipsum[3]


\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion caused. `hypcap` gives an error if there's no caption. I know I forgot to include it in the MWE.

Comment: I'd never heard of that package but its manual says you can use \captstartfalse just before the figure to turn off the behaviour see example top of page 3

Comment: disabling the behaviour of `\capstart` made it possible *not* to use `\caption` at all as you suggested. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's probably better to add the `\capstartfalse` and `\capstrarttrue` method.